# Who's on my wireless network

Tags: wireless-networking

I have a shared internet connection and it seems often very loaded. Is it possible to see the number of computers connected to my wireless network? And is it possible to see which computers that loads the computer the most?

Comment: I'd suggest posting this to - http://serverfault.com.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the IP range of your wirless LAN you could try [nmap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nmap)

A ping sweep would reveal the connected hosts:

```
nmap -sP 192.168.1.1-254
```